# Can I use one lambda function in C++ to get the best and worst score of my array?

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm practising lambda function in C++, so I'm trying to get the best and the worst score of some students.
I got the best score, but I'm asking myself if I can get the worst score from the same used lambda function, or should I create another score for the worst student?
If I can do this, how can I do it?

Here is my code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
struct Student{
    std::string name;
    int points;
};
int main(){
    std::array<Student, 8> arr{
        { { "Yannik", 3 },
          { "Monica", 5 },
          { "Christine", 2 },
          { "Anna", 8 }, // Dan has the most points (8).
          { "Paul", 4 },
          { "Mood", 1 },
          { "Barbara", 10 },
          { "Jack", 5 } }
    };
    const auto score{ std::max_element(arr.begin(),arr.end(),[](const Student &student, const Student &student1){
        return (student.points<student1.points);
    })};
    std::cout<<score->name<<" has " <<score->points <<" points\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about using [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)?

Comment: Well, you're already using `std::max_element`. You might be interested in `std::min_element` and `std::minmax_element`.

Comment: @NathanPierson do you mean like this?                                                        const auto score{ std::max_element(arr.begin(),arr.end(),[](const Student &student, const Student &student1){
        return student.points<student1.points;  
    })};
    const auto score2{ std::min_element(arr.begin(),arr.end(),[](const Student &student, const Student &student1){
        return student.points<student1.points;
    })};

Comment: @midomsry You can call both `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` separately to get the minimum and maximum values, but there is also a `std::minmax_element` algorithm that return both values to you and it is more efficient, since you only traverse the container once.

Comment: @darcamo That's what I was looking for! thank you so much :-)

Comment: If you are on c++20, using algorithms from the ranges library is a "nicer" alternative, since it support "projections". l have posted it as an answer, since it would be too much for a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get both the minimum and maximum value of a container you can simply use the `std::minmax_element` algorithm, since it is more efficient than calling `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` separately.

The code becomes something like

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Student {
    std::string name;
    int points;
};

int main() {
    std::array<Student, 8> arr{{{"Yannik", 3},
                                {"Monica", 5},
                                {"Christine", 2},
                                {"Anna", 8},  // Dan has the most points (8).
                                {"Paul", 4},
                                {"Mood", 1},
                                {"Barbara", 10},
                                {"Jack", 5}}};

    auto [min_iter, max_iter] = std::minmax_element(
        arr.begin(), arr.end(),
        [](const Student &student, const Student &student1) { return (student.points < student1.points); });

    std::cout << min_iter->name << " has " << min_iter->points << " points\n";
    std::cout << max_iter->name << " has " << max_iter->points << " points\n";

    return 0;
}
```

With  C++20 we can also use the "ranges version" with `std::ranges::minmax_element` and pass the whole array, instead of passing the pair of iterators.

The relevant line becomes

```cpp
auto [min_iter, max_iter] = std::ranges::minmax_element(
        arr, [](const Student &student, const Student &student1) { return (student.points < student1.points); });
```

As in the previous case without ranges, the lambda function passed to the algorithm is the "comparator" we use to compare the two `Student` objects. But there is a better way, IMHO. We can use `std::less` as the comparator, but tell the ranges library to compare using the `points` field of the `Student` class. This can be done using [projections](https://www.cppstories.com/2020/10/understanding-invoke.html/).

The relevant line becomes

```cpp
auto [min_iter, max_iter] = std::ranges::minmax_element(arr, {}, &Student::points);
```

The second argument passed to the algorithm (`{}`) means "use the default value", which is `std::less`. The third argument is the projection. The projection could also be a lambda function that returns the value that the comparator should use, but in this case it's cleaner to just specify the class field we want to use for comparison.

The full code becomes

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Student {
    std::string name;
    int points;
};

int main() {
    std::array<Student, 8> arr{{{"Yannik", 3},
                                {"Monica", 5},
                                {"Christine", 2},
                                {"Anna", 8},  // Dan has the most points (8).
                                {"Paul", 4},
                                {"Mood", 1},
                                {"Barbara", 10},
                                {"Jack", 5}}};

    auto [min_iter, max_iter] = std::ranges::minmax_element(arr, {}, &Student::points);

    std::cout << min_iter->name << " has " << min_iter->points << " points\n";
    std::cout << max_iter->name << " has " << max_iter->points << " points\n";

    return 0;
}
```